# How to run Texlive with SUA?

Tags: windows, linux, texlive, sua

Is it possible to run the linux version on SUA (Subsystem for Unix Application) on windows?
or if I have to use the windows version, is it possible to use it with SUA?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you want to achieve. Is there a reason not to just use the Windows build?

Comment: I want to be able to use SUA with it. (Use vim in SUA to type out the documents and compile within my editor like on linux).
As far as I know, SUA cannot run dos prompt commands, and I believe latex for windows only has dos commands...

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't just use the Windows build of vim?

Comment: well I could, but Im wondering if I am able to use SUA instead.
you see if i am able to this would make my life a lot easier, I sometimes use kwrite to do grammar check on my tex file too, just easier to read i guess.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I just feel like it would be easier to do this with native Windows tools.

Comment: oh yea, sometimes its definitely easier to use the native windows tools. Its just I been trying to mimic my old environment bit by bit lately. After I got xming to work with SUA, I just pull x-applications from my remote linux machine all the time LOL